# ability to select vCPU/core spec on Google Compute

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform

It looks like the finest I get to select whether through the API or through the Google Compute's OWA is a whole family/architecture (Broadwell, Skylake, etc.) However, performance and instruction set support varies greatly within those architectures. For example, one look at the Skylake family tells you that CPU speed varies from 2.2 to over 3 GHz and there is also a wide variation in the instruction sets and extensions supported by the members of the family:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skylake_(microarchitecture)

In light of that, I have the following question: does Google provide any guarantees that the two VM's selected to be within the same family would perform comparably? Is there any way to select the spec for your cores with more granularity?

Thanks.

Boris.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.  Nowadays you can specifically [select the CPU platform the VM will be using](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/05/Compute-Engine-updates-bring-Skylake-GA-Extended-Memory-and-more-VM-flexibility.html).  You can do that through the Cloud Console, CLI or API. Certainly not all the [CPUs families are available in every Region](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/). Additional information can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/specify-min-cpu-platform)

Comment: Carlos, thank you!

Yes, you can select a particular CPU family - I know that, and that is great! However, it appears that I can not refine my selection beyond that point. Is that accurate, or did I miss something?